# Shortest Path Problem as a Minimum Cost Flow Problem

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming, network-flow

I have to formulate the well known shortest path problem as a min-cost flow problem, but I don't know how to do it.

I need your help and suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: both shortest path and min-cost flow determine the minimum of a sum.  Try to establish a mapping between the sums.  We can't really help you further until you demonstrate that you actually know what these algorithms mean and show your attempts at encoding one into the other.  It sincerely sounds like you might not even understand each algorithm itself, since once you do, working out the connection is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Write them both down as an LP and you see the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://laurentlessard.com/teaching/524-intro-to-optimization) lecture, let's take this sample problem

[image]

Start is s end is x. Let's give indices as $s=1$, $t=2$, $y=3$, $x=4$, $z=5$, and let's design the $x$ vector to be

$$
x = [x_{12}, x_{13}, x_{23}, x_{24}, x_{32}, x_{34}, x_{35}, x_{45}, x_{51}, x_{54}]
$$

The incidence matrix and code is below

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np

A = [
     [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0],
     [ -1,  1,  1,  -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0],
     [ 0,  -1,  -1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0, 0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  -1,  0,  -1,  0,  1,  0, -1],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  -1,  -1,  1, 1]]


b = [1, 0, 0, -1, 0]

c= [10, 5, 2, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 7, 6]
A = np.array(A); b = np.array(b); c = np.array(c)

res = linprog(c, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)
res = np.round(res.x)
print (res)
```

The result will be

```
[0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

which implies the path ['s', 'y', 't','x'], the same solution from Djikstra.

Also see [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654374/can-shortest-path-problems-solved-faster-as-network-flow-lp-than-djikstra).

Comment: Good answer . However, I want to point out that the incidence matrix does not represent the given graph. Coincidentally, the solution for the presented example is indeed the optimal path, but this is not true for other pairs of start and end points.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article on wikipedia where it explains how to reduce the minimum cost flow to a Shortest Path Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem :

> The solution is to remove the capacity constraint.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/593332)

Comment: I tried to improve my answer