# Can Shortest Path Problems Solved Faster as Network Flow LP Than Dijkstra

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, convex-optimization, computer-science, linear-programming

Dijkstra's algorithm is known to solve shortest path problems in $O(|V|^2)$ where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ is set of edges.

However I just finished studying minimum cost network flow problems, implemented a few solutions for shortest path calculations, that can be solved as LPs, which always finds the optimal solution. If we think of the code behind the scenes, LPs can be numerically solved through log-barrier approach and the Newton's method. Then, since Newton steps never exceed 10-15 steps, and in each the biggest cost is calculating the Jacobian matrix, which in case of a network problem is banded, structured, so it can be inverted in $O(|E|)$, meaning faster than Dijkstra performance.  $|V|^2$ means potentially checking all pairs of nodes, but networks are sparse, each node is not connected to each other node, $O(|E|)$ only pays a price proportional to edges that exist.

Would this be a correct assessment?

Comment: I don't have any practical experience in solving min-cost flow LPs with log-barrier, but the place where I'm a bit skeptical of your approach is the claim that $O(1)$ Newton steps are enough. Why wouldn't the number of steps grow with the size of the network?

Comment: Good point on $O(1)$ - Newton converges extremely fast independent of the size of the network. I've never seen, or heard of, anyone's Newton method implementation ever taking more than 15 steps, that's why I consider it constant.

Comment: Ah just noticed the Wikipedia article on Djikstra says it calculates shortest path 'from a start node to every other node'. That could change things little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.08929

Comment: That seems to be a max flow problem, not a min-cost flow??

Comment: Is this paper https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-13075-0_59 useful?

Comment: @Song, paper looks interesting, says best known bound is $O(m^{3/2})$ where $m$ is (I am guessing paper doesnt say) number of nodes, and that is better than Djikstra.

Comment: @NetSmoothMF Usually $m$ refers to the number of edges and $n$ to the number of vertices unless the paper specifies otherwise. $O(m^{3/2})$ is still potentially better that $O(n^2)$ for sparse networks.

Comment: $m$ is usually the number of edges in the graph

Comment: This paper could be also useful for you. https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01717